# Symfony 3: Logging from an abstract class to a repository

Tags: class, symfony, logging, repository

I have a problem configuring my REST API on Symfony 3.
I use an abstract class to do GET, PUT, POST, DELETE on a CRM.
From time to time we have timeout errors, I would like to record these errors in a Repository (database table).
To record error from controller i used :

```
$this->logger->logInterface('WSBPM', "WSGETBPM", $message, 1, 0, (string)date('Y-m-d His'));
```

Here is the code in my class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Classes;
use AppBundle\Repository\BPMInterfacesRepository;
use AppBundle\Service\EmailSender;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
/**
 * @package Creatio
 */
abstract class CreatioWS {

    private $em;
    /**
     * @var BPMInterfacesRepository
     */
    private $logger;

    function __construct( EntityManagerInterface $em ) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->logger = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:BPMInterfaces');
    }   

    public function WSGETBPM($collection, $apiQuery) {
    ...
    ...
    //on error, i do:
    $this->logger->logInterface('WSBPM', "WSGETBPM", $message, 1, 0, (string)date('Y-m-d His'));
    ...
    }
}
```

If an error occurs (timeout), I would like to record it.
But the server answers me:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal Server Error",
        "exception": [
            {
                "message": "Call to a member function logInterface() on null",
                "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
                "trace": [
                    {
                        "namespace": "",
                        "short_class": "",
                        "class": "",
                        "type": "",
                        "function": "",
                        "file": "C:\\workspace\\api\\src\\AppBundle\\Classes\\CreatioWS.php",
    ...
```

Can somebody help me to record data into a repository from my class
Thank you